# SQL Keyword search

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a search Function on my website using PHP and SQL.
I am trying to make it so that when i search for a keyword in it displays items matching the key word

This is my [Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6X2z.png)

If i was to search "rice chicken" it would return both Davida and roys, i would like it to only return Davids as it matches both words and not roys as roys only matches rice

Thos is my current code.

```
$search = $_GET['query'];

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("axamenu");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT  * FROM menu WHERE CONTAINS(items,'$.search')");
if(mysql_num_rows($query) >= 1) {
    while($a = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo "<a href='".$a['profileurl']."'>".$a['restaurant']."</a><p>".$a['menutype']."</p><hr/>";
    }

} else {
    echo "Oh no! Nothing was found.";
}
```

Comment: show your table architecture with data .....that will be better to resolve your problem

Comment: Why don't you use items like '%".$search."%' ? Do you have problem with like ?

Comment: 1. **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7. Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. **You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: I understand this is not secure, that is not a concern for me right now. This is for a website search input so there can only be 1 search term, or else spiting this would work.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your query in this way

```
$where = '';
$string = "thi sdas asd";
$search = explode(" ",$string);
if(sizeof($search)>1)
{
$where = "1=1";
    foreach($search=>$key as $val){
        $where .= "or items like %".$val."%"; 
    }
}
else
{

$where = "items like %".$search[0]."%"
}

$query = mysql_query("SELECT  * FROM menu WHERE ".$where);
//rest of your code goes here
```

**Note: Stop using deprecated and insecure mysql_*-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7. Use MySQLi or PDO instead**

Answer (score 0):

If you only want davids result as "rice chicken",
you can split your string as rice and chicken and query as

`SELECT * from menu WHERE items REGEXP 'rice' AND items REGEXP 'chicken'`

> you will get only one result

**NOTE: using REGEXP can slow down result for bulk data retrieving**

Answer (score 0):

```
$search = $_GET['query'];

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("axamenu");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT  * FROM menu WHERE 
items LIKE '%".$search."%'");
if(mysql_num_rows($query) >= 1) 
{
    while($a = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
    {
        echo "<a href='".$a['profileurl']."'>".$a['restaurant']."</a><p>".$a['menutype']."</p><hr/>";
     }

 } 
 else 
 {
     echo "Oh no! Nothing was found.";
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try with this and let us if that works.

```
select * from table_name where items like 'rice%' or items like 'chicken%';
```

Comment: Looking at the question, this would not do what the OP asks.

Comment: No need to down wote, if that doesn't work he should be the one who will add the comment :(

Comment: That's not how this site works. If someone sees that an answer is clearly wrong (not solving the actual question) + doesn't explain anything about _why_ the OP should try it, then you actually _should_ downvote it. It's community driven and we all help out to weed out the good and the bad answers.